# Python unittest does not notice if you accidentally duplicate a test

Tags: python, python-unittest

If I modify the [basic example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) from the docs and accidentally on purpose duplicate a test:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It returns exactly the same thing as if it were not duplicated:

```
python3 basictest.py 
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

If you change one of the duplicated tests so it fails, the failure will or won't show up depending on which of the duplicates you modify. So I did this by accident genuinely while writing tests which were just slightly different from each other. What if you did this in a program where they were not just next to each other but at opposite ends of the script. Why does it not warn you if you have duplicate tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to detect duplicates in a class defined like this. As you can see, when the class is just being created via the metaclass, one of the duplicate functions has already been chosen:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        print(name, namespace)

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class Dupe(metaclass=Meta):
    def a(self):
        ...

    def a(self):
        ...
```

This outputs:

```
Dupe {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Dupe', 'a': <function Dupe.a at 0x8f5be84>}
```

If you wanted to detect duplicates, you'd need to wrap *each function* in a decorator and let it decide whether a particular function is a duplicate or not. *How* to make this decision is another question: for example, you may keep track of all the names of the functions already defined and then simply check if the given function's name already exists in the list.

Comment: Thanks, it is not technically possible as it is written for it to warn you. You seem to be saying they could have gone to some extra effort so that it warns you, which they did not. @DanielRoseman emphasises the _why should it_. Well good to know why does it not, it is subjective whether it _should_ or not. I personally think it should given that tests are about coverage, making sure nothing gets through the gaps, it would be good if it caught a very likely error which can mask whether a test is doing anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

Why should it warn you? More to the point, how could it? Unittest classes are no different from any other class; as with any other class they store their attributes - including methods - in a dict. And as with any dict, if you assign two values with the same key one will overwrite the other